# Android - Custom AutoCompleteTextView layout

Tags: android, view, spinner

The AutoCompleteTextView drop-down has a large font size. I want to change it to something smaller. I think the way to do it is to overwrite the

`android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line`. Please can someone let me know how to do it.

Thank you.
Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[setTextAppearance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextAppearance%28android.content.Context,%20int%29) should allow you modify text size.

Comment: Thanks youssef. will check it out.